# Center Image in VStack leading alignment

Tags: swiftui

I'm having troubles figuring out the proper solution to centre an `Image` inside a `VStack` with an alignment of `.leading`. I've attempted and got these results but is there a more efficient way instead of adding two `Spacer()`'s in an `HStack`?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Text("Title ")
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName:"star.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.all)
    }
}
```

[image: alignment]

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
ScrollView {
    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("Title ")
        Image(systemName:"star.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        Divider()
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks good, thank you @Asperi. Is adding two `frame`'s frowned upon?

Comment: those are different modifiers (even though called both as frame) and each gives new view. It is like embedding one view into another with different bounds.